# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException'

Tags: xcode

I am working on setting page for iPhone.

When I click account menu on setting page. it crashes and shows me this error.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM replaceObjectAtIndex:withObject:]: index 4 beyond bounds [0 .. 3]'

Can you tell me where do I suppose to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Xcode debugger, set either a global breakpoint at "`replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject`" or look for any and all calls to "`replaceObjectAtIndex: withObject`" in your code and set breakpoints there and see if you can catch where / when the exception happens.

Here's a bit of help from [Apple's Xcode documentation, I'm looking at a chapter called "Breakpoint Navigator"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010433-CH1-SW1).